# Sencha touch: toolbar is not scrolling properly

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a toolbar which is created like this -

```
toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                            docked: 'bottom',
                            scrollable: {direction: 'horizontal', directionLock: true},
                            hidden: true,
                            items: thumbItems
                        });
```

I am using the following code to scroll it -

```
toolbar.getScrollable()
         .getScroller()
         .scrollTo(scrollUnit * scrollAmount, 
                   0, {type: 'slide', duration: '1000', easing: 'linear'});
```

It's working fine when the toolbar is visible. If this code is executed while the toolbar is hidden, the scroller simply doesn't scroll. I can see in the console that this code is being executed, but the scroller is simply not moving from it's position.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This way of creating component is deprecated in ST2. Use Ext.create('Ext.toolbar',CONFIG_OBJECT);

Comment: @TDeBailleul: The scroll is working! Wow, I didn't expect that! Please write this as the answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: Ha ha, didn't expect that either :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens because the way you create your toolbar is deprecated in Sencha Touch 2

You should do it like so :

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar',{
  docked: 'bottom',
  scrollable: {direction: 'horizontal', directionLock: true},
  hidden: true,
  items: thumbItems
});
```

Hope this helped.